# How to disable whitelabel error page in application.yaml (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a legacy Java monolith backend, serving REST APIs (spring boot v1.5.9, gradle) in hand which I have to maintain from time to time. A request came to disable such an error page:

"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 10 13:41:12 CET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)."

I tried to get rid of this message but most of the advices explain how to remove it in a "application.properties" file, which my project doesn't have at all. Instead, I have application.yaml files, where I added this configuration:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

But I still see the same error page.

Other advices tell me to do something on "main" class, which my project unfortunately doesn't have, either.

I also tried to implement `ErrorController` to get my own Error page but my controller is not registered at all. Standard project structure recommendations are not followed on this legacy app, so any link to example structures on spring boot documentations will not help me.

Any advice is appreciated to disable the whitelabel error page or implementing `ErrorController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable default "Whitelabel Error Page", you can add:

```
server:
    //..optionally, some other properties
    error:
        whitelabel:
            enabled: false
    //..optionally, some other properties
```

in your `application.yml`.

However, if you want to *override* that page, instead of disabling it and displaying application server's default error page, you have few ways:

1. Create your custom `error.html` page, place it under your `templates` folder (or wherever your view are being picked up from), and it will be automatically picked up by Spring Boot's default `BasicErrorController` as a generic error page, that is - for all HTTP error codes;
2. You can be more specific and create different error pages for different HTTP error codes.
   Name your error file with the HTTP status code you want to handle and save it in `resources\templates\error\`. This way, you may have several error pages and they will be used for corresponding HTTP errors.
   `404.html`, for instance, will be returned when HTTP 404 happens.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling works, but I don't have a templates folder because there are no views at all in this monolith backend which only works as a REST API server. I created one under one of the resources folders but it didn't work. I give up.

Comment: REST APIs don't return views. You have to decide what you want to do.. REST APIs return error response, with some information in it, like error code, reason, etc. If there are no views at all, then you might want to construct the view, dynamically, and write that view and `content-type` header, both, into your `HttpServletResponse` object.. you can extract this view construction into some other method. Using views in REST API is not a good idea.